# How to share SQLite database?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sqlite, visual-sourcesafe-2005

I'm working on one project which is in vs2010 . And for that project my team is using SQLite database server. And we have added our project in source safe . I want to share SQLite database too. Is this possible? if yes then how to do this?

thanks.

Comment: SQLite isn't a database server.

Comment: Neil is correct to point out your loose use of the term "server", especially in the context of your question about sharing. SQLite does not use a client-server message-passing architecture nor does it run as a process as a database server typically does. Moreover, during writes, SQLite locks the  file in its entirety, not just a range of bytes within the file, as LAN-based "shared-file" databases (Paradox, dBase, FoxPro, MS-Access, Revelation) do/did. SQLite is an excellent small-footprint database but it was not designed from the ground up to address concurrent multi-user demand.

Comment: @ Neil Butterworth: http://www.sqlite.org/serverless.html refer this documentation.

Comment: I have read it - it confirms what I said.

Answer (score 0):

Just share the file. 
SQLite is just a file based database, not a central transaction based database. 
Everytime you commit to the db, you will need to commit the SQLite file with source safe. 
For small time development this might not be too bad.

Answer (score 0):

TelsaBoil is correct - you can simply add the DB as a binary file to VSS. There's another thing you may want to do besides, or as an alternative: dump the schema to a text file and recreate the DB on each developer machine with the .schema  command (You can dump data with the .data command: http://www.sqlite.org/sqlite.html).

I've found it highly useful to have a version-controlled create script along the database so it is easy to review changes. While not completely standardized, it can also be used as a starting point if you need to change database.